# Представления в SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Как добавить данные с помощью представления?

возможно я не до конца понимаю, что такое представление.

Comment: добавить данные куда ? Представления обычно для выборки используются, а не для добавления. Хотя можно написать триггер на представление который будет что то добавлять в таблицу, но было бы логично что бы такое представление содержало все обязательные поля таблицы

Comment: есть задание: Создать представление, содержащее сведения о
сотрудниках и добавить с помощью него нового
сотрудника.

Comment: ну тогда я бы предложил все таки выбирать не только fname но и другие поля, по крайней мере те поля, которые вы собираетесь заполнять при вставке и так же первичный ключ таблицы.

Comment: Во-первых, представление должно быть обновляемым. Не все вьюхи таковыми являются. Во-вторых, конкретно с вашим (верните код на место) есть такая проблема: при добавлении сотрудника с датой раньше 2014 года он добавится в таблицу, но не отобразится в этом представлении. Дейт в своём талмуде об этом хорошо писал.

Comment: Этот view относился к другому заданию) Спасибо я уже добавил с помощью вьюшки, но если вам не сложно, скажите где можно почитать про view хорошую статью (про обновляемые и не обновляемые)

Comment: oracle отличается отличной родной документацией https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF01504